# RxNet - Restart Observables

Tags: c#, .net, observable, system.reactive

I'm using observables to initialize an interval of numbers after 5 seconds. It works the first time, but when I restart it, it doesn't wait for the 5 seconds (only restarts the sequence). How could I restart the observable?

Here it's my code

`

```
class Program
   {
      static readonly Subject<int> subject = new Subject<int>();
      static readonly Subject<bool> disconnect = new Subject<bool>();

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var observable = subject
           // Initial 5 seconds of delay
           .Select(_ => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
           .Switch()
           .Select(_ => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
           .Switch()
           .TakeUntil(disconnect);

         observable.Subscribe(lowNum =>
         {
            Console.WriteLine(lowNum);
         });

         // Restart sequence after 10 seconds
         var timer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
         timer.Subscribe(_ => subject.OnNext(1));

         Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }
```

`

I'd expect to restart the observable with the initial 5 seconds of delay